# Odometry model two wheeled robot with kinect

Tags: navigation, odometry, kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to implement the navigation with ROS and a two-wheeled robot with Kinect, I have access to the readings of the velocity and pose of the wheel encoders , so I need an odometry motion model .
So is there some equation  already done  for the odometry in ROS that I can use for this purpose? or any person have experience with this topic?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67026/odometry-model-two-wheeled-robot-with-kinect/) by [salime](https://answers.ros.org/users/5267/salime/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest that you look at the [TurtleBot](http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/TurtleBot) code for some examples.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1